# Sqlserver connector tried to access protected method

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I m getting this error in connector

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnectorConfig$$Lambda$748/0x0000000800fe6628
 tried to access protected method 'int io.debezium.config.CommonConnectorConfig.validateServerNameIsDifferentFromHistoryTopicName(io.debezium.config.Configuration, io.debezium.config.Field, io.debezium.config.Field$ValidationOutput)'
 (io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorConfig$$Lambda$748/0x0000000800fe6628 and io.debezium.config.CommonConnectorConfig 
 are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader @351d0846) 
 at io.debezium.config.Field$Validator.lambda$and$0(Field.java:214)
```

Comment: Try running Debezium with Java 8

Comment: It is already running in adopt open jdk 8.this was working fine till last week.we encountered this error when we tried to create new connector